# com.parse.ParseException: function not found in ParseCloud

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, parse-cloud-code

so this is the `main.js` file in my cloud:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("addChannelToUser",function(request,response)){

var userId = request.params.userId;
var listId = request.params.listId;

var User = Parse.Object.extend("User"),
    user = new User({ objectId: userId });

    user.add("channels",listId);

     Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
        user.save().then(function(user) {
        response.success(user);
        }, function(error) {
            response.error(error)
    });
});
```

and this is where I call it from my app:

```
  ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("addChannelToUser",params,
   new FunctionCallback<Object>() {
  @Override
     public void done(Object o, ParseException e) {
     if(e != null){
     Log.d("cloud error", e.toString());
     }else{
      Log.d("cloud", "success");
     }
     }
   });
```

my goal is to add the lisId to the "channel" field of a user with userId.
of course this user is not the user logged in the device so I obviously need to use the master key...

anyway, I keep getting the error "function not found", please help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copy your code to my main.js file and try to deploy the code to Parse Cloud. However, Parse generates me a syntax error where I correct as follows;

```
Parse.Cloud.define("addChannelToUser",function(request,response)
{

var userId = request.params.userId;
var listId = request.params.listId;

var User = Parse.Object.extend("User"),
user = new User({ objectId: userId });

user.add("channels",listId);

 Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    user.save().then(function(user) {
    response.success(user);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error)
    });
});
```

You can extract where you make mistake. The cloud function is tested in Parse environment. It is working. Hope this helps.

Regards.